# How do I write this ruby rake task in straight postgresql?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

Here is the rake task:

```
task :map_comment_to_user => :environment do
    Comment.all.each do |c|
      a         = Admin.where(mongo_id: c.mongo_user_id).first
      u         = User.where(email: a.email).first
      c.user_id = u.id
      c.save
    end
  end
```

I screwed up a migration from Admin => User tables, and the email being unique allows me to stitch them back together.  But it's so slow.

How do I write the above in straight PSQL?

```
UPDATE comments c 
SET c.user_id = u.id 
FROM users u admins a 
WHERE c.mongo_user_id == a.mongo_id 
  AND u.email = a.email; ???
```

Comment: are there any associations between `comments/admins/users` right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is very close. It just require a few minor syntax changes.

```
UPDATE comments c
SET user_id = u.id
FROM users u, admins a
WHERE c.mongo_user_id = a.mongo_id
  AND u.email = a.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can save you plenty of cost of object initialization and speed up things for you.

```
Comment.select(:id,:user_id).each do |c|
  email = Admin.where(mongo_id: c.mongo_user_id).pluck(:email).first
  uid = User.where(email: email).pluck(:id).first
  c.user_id = uid
  c.save
end
```